# What is difference between empty_clob and createtemporary in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, lob

Can anyone please tell what is the basic difference between `empty_clob` and `createtemporary`.

Here is my code.

```
/*empty_clob vs createtemporary()*/
DECLARE
    elob   CLOB;
    tlob   CLOB;
BEGIN
    IF elob IS NULL THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('elob is null');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('elob has a locator');
    END IF;

    IF tlob IS NULL THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('tlob is null');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('tlob has a locator');
    END IF;

    elob := empty_clob;
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(tlob, false);

    IF elob IS NULL THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('elob is null');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('elob has a locator');
    END IF;

    IF tlob IS NULL THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('tlob is null');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('tlob has a locator');
    END IF;

    dbms_lob.freetemporary(elob); -- exception
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(tlob);
END;
```

and why I can not pass an empty object locator which is returned by `empty_clob` to any dbms_lob function/procedure.

Comment: Do you have an example error message of a function not excepting an `empty_clob`? This works for me: `SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(empty_clob()) FROM dual;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary lob is a full blown LOB, the only difference to a normal, filled LOB is that it is not associated with a table and that it lives in a temporary tablespace. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96591/adl11tmp.htm) for details. The purpose is to manipulate your LOB in the temp space until you are ready to store it in a normal table row.

However, `empty_clob` initialized a LOB locator and creates a proper LOB of length 0. I copied Julian Dykes' example from his excellent presentation [LOB Internals](http://www.juliandyke.com/Presentations/Presentations.php):

[image]

So you cannot call `dbms_lob.freetemporary` on an `empty_clob`, because it's not in the temp tablespace.

EDIT:

Once the `empty_clob` is stored in a table, you can inspect it's LOBID:

```
CREATE TABLE t (c CLOB, e CLOB DEFAULT EMPTY_CLOB()) LOB (e) STORE AS SECUREFILE;
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES (null);

SELECT DBMS_LOBUTIL.getinode(e).lobid   AS lobid,
       DBMS_LOBUTIL.getinode(e).length  AS length,
       DBMS_LOBUTIL.getinode(e).extents AS extents
  FROM t;

LOBID                  LENGTH   EXTENTS
0000000100000007E5E1   0        0
```

According to Julian, the LOBID is generated from a sequence, which means it is quite likely unique across the database.